# How to turn off telemetry for SQL 2016

Tags: sql-server

Installing SQL 2016 automatically turns on all of the "CEIP", or Customer Experience Improvement Program elements.  These elements report back to Microsoft about various aspects of your installation experience as well as your feature usage.  I want to turn it off, because it's all blocked by our firewalls anyway and I don't need the headache.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Turns out, doing this seems pretty easy.  Set the following registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130\CustomerFeedback=0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130\EnableErrorReporting=0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.TESTINSTANCE\CPE\CustomerFeedback=0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.TESTINSTANCE\CPE\EnableErrorReporting=0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.TESTINSTANCE\CPE\CustomerFeedback=0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.TESTINSTANCE\CPE\EnableErrorReporting=0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.TESTINSTANCE\CPE\CustomerFeedback=0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.TESTINSTANCE\CPE\EnableErrorReporting=0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130\CustomerFeedback=0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130\EnableErrorReporting=0
```

If any of the keys don't exist, then that's OK, because you apparently didn't install that feature.

Disable the following services:

```
SQL Analysis Services CEIP
SQL Server CEIP service
SQL Server Integration Services CEIP service 13.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Don't know why, but the three telemetry service used a lot of ram on our server...

Comment: If those specific keys do not exist, maybe you have another version installed, and those keys are still nearby (like SQL Server 2017 instead of 2016, having version number 140 instead of 130).

Comment: @dakab You are right - just change the number to match your current version.  However, with the separation of SSRS from SQL, the registry key has changed.  It's now `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SSRS\CPE`

Answer (score 26):

Here is a Powershell script that will disable all telemetry CEIP services, and will update the registry to disable CustomerFeedback and EnableErrorReporting:

```
Get-Service | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*telemetry*' -or $_.DisplayName -like '*CEIP*' } | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        $servicename = $_.Name; 
        $displayname = $_.DisplayName; 
        Set-Service -Name $servicename  -StartupType Disabled 
        $serviceinfo = Get-Service -Name $servicename 
        $startup = $serviceinfo.StartType
        Write-Host "$servicename : $startup : $displayname";  
    }

Set-Location "HKLM:\"
$sqlentries = @( "\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\", "\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\" ) 
Get-ChildItem -Path $sqlentries -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object {
        $keypath = $_.Name
        (Get-ItemProperty -Path $keypath).PSObject.Properties |
             Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "CustomerFeedback" -or $_.Name -eq "EnableErrorReporting" } |
             ForEach-Object {
                $itemporpertyname = $_.Name
                $olditemporpertyvalue = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $keypath -Name $itemporpertyname
                Set-ItemProperty  -Path $keypath -Name $itemporpertyname -Value 0
                $newitemporpertyvalue = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path $keypath -Name $itemporpertyname
                Write-Host "$keypath.$itemporpertyname = $olditemporpertyvalue --> $newitemporpertyvalue" 
             }
    }
```

Comment: @ScottRFrost Yep, it will. SQL 2017 is under the registry as 14 or 140, but it still recurses through them and sets them up

Comment: Still works for the 2019 version!

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the "Error and Usage Report Settings" app that is installed with Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

This [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3153756/how-to-configure-sql-server-2016-to-send-feedback-to-microsoft)  shows the details with pretty pictures. Might save fat-finger editing your registry.  In my testing it did not require a service restart, it just worked.

Comment: There's no pictures that I can see, but the text is good enough "To start SQL Server Error and Usage Reporting, click or tap Start, and then search on "Error" in the search box. The SQL Server Error and Usage Reporting item will be displayed"

Comment: @JerryHung I turned this off but the CEIP services are still running. Did you reboot? I think maybe this app just turns off the sending but not the collection. I stopped and disabled the Telemetry (CEIP) services.

Answer (score 4):

Necromancing. 
Quick-fix version:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130]
"EnableErrorReporting"=dword:00000000
"CustomerFeedback"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130]
"EnableErrorReporting"=dword:00000000
"CustomerFeedback"=dword:00000000




[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\CPE]
"EnableErrorReporting"=dword:00000000
"CustomerFeedback"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS13.MSSQLSERVER\CPE]
"EnableErrorReporting"=dword:00000000
"CustomerFeedback"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\CPE]
"EnableErrorReporting"=dword:00000000
"CustomerFeedback"=dword:00000000
```

Search-and-replace MSSQLSERVER with your instance name.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's doing installs with Powershell Desired state configurations (sqlserverdsc/sqlsetup) below will handle the db engine and SSIS telemetry services.  I'm sure you can modify other registry values previous users posted for AS/RS.  This assumes SQL 2016 and default named instance and you'd be using the computermanagementdsc.

```
        Registry RegistrySqlIsCustFeedback
        {
            Ensure      = "Present"  # You can also set Ensure to "Absent"
            Key         = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\CPE"
            ValueType   = "Dword"
            ValueName   = "CustomerFeedback"
            ValueData   = "0"
        }

        Registry RegistrySqlIsErrReporting
        {
            Ensure      = "Present"  # You can also set Ensure to "Absent"
            Key         = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\CP"
            ValueType   = "Dword"
            ValueName   = "EnableErrorReporting"
            ValueData   = "0"
        }
        
        Registry RegistrySqlCustFeedback64
        {
            Ensure      = "Present"  # You can also set Ensure to "Absent"
            Key         = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130"
            ValueType   = "Dword"
            ValueName   = "CustomerFeedback"
            ValueData   = "0"
        }
        Registry RegistryErrReporting64
        {
            Ensure      = "Present"  # You can also set Ensure to "Absent"
            Key         = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130"
            ValueType   = "Dword"
            ValueName   = "EnableErrorReporting"
            ValueData   = "0"
        }
        Registry RegistrySqlCustFeedback
        {
            Ensure      = "Present"  # You can also set Ensure to "Absent"
            Key         = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130"
            ValueType   = "Dword"
            ValueName   = "CustomerFeedback"
            ValueData   = "0"
        }
        Registry RegistryErrReporting
        {
            Ensure      = "Present"  # You can also set Ensure to "Absent"
            Key         = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130"
            ValueType   = "Dword"
            ValueName   = "EnableErrorReporting"
            ValueData   = "0"
        }
```

Comment: I am curious if anyone viewing this thread has also attempted to disable or drop the telemetry_xevents session as well as the NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY user account.  I've seen Kendra Little's explanation of use, but little elaboration on pulling the plug.